# Bash regex =~ doesn’t support multiline mode?

Tags: regex, bash

using =~ operator to match output of a command and grab group from it. Code is as follows:

> Comamndout=$(cmd) Match=‘^hello world’ If $Comamndout =~ $Match; then
> echo something fi

Commandout is in pattern
Something
Hello world

But if statement is failing.
Is bash regex support multiline search with everyline start with ^ and end with $.

Comment: The code example here is invalid bash syntax (is it missing `[[ ]]`?), and also misformatted. Please edit your question to use [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and also bash code that correctly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A [mre] needs to be code we can run ourselves without changes to see the same problem. Using `If` instead of `if` causes a _different_ problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `=~` operator doesn't perform a multiline search. A newline must be matched literally:

```bash
string=$(cmd)
regexp='(^|'$'\n'')hello world'

if [[ $string =~ $regexp ]]; then
  echo matches
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`=~` would treat multiple lines as one line.

```
if [[ $(echo -e "abc\nd") =~ ^a.*d$ ]]; then
  echo "find a string '$(echo -e "abc\nd")' that starts with a and ends with d"
fi
```

Output:

```
find a string 'abc
d' that starts with a and ends with d
```

---

P.S.
When processing multiple lines, it is common to use `grep` or `read` with either re-direct or pipeline.

- For a `grep` and pipeline example:

  ```
  # to find a line start with either a or e
  echo -e "abc\nd\ne" | grep -E "^[ae]"
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  abc
  e
  ```
- For a `read` and redirect example:

  ```
  while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^a} ]] ; then
      echo "find a line '${line}' start with a"
    fi
  done <<< $(echo -e "abc\nd\ne")
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  find a line 'abc' start with a
  ```

---

P.S.
`-e` of `echo` means translate following `\n` into new line. `-E` of `grep` means using the extended regular expression to match.